# image overflowed after rotation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After rotating an image,it started overflowing. I want the image not to overflow without hiding overflowed part. I **used rotate() fuction** to rotate an image and it **overflowed**. **Any solutions**?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Don't rotate the image, put it in a container and rotate that.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative margin to adjust the image or you can reduce the size of the image.

```
// make image moves up
margin-top: -10px;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i rotated the container and it didn't overflowed.